# What's supposed to be the problem in this query?

Tags: sql, mariadb, localhost

I don't understand what's wrong, I just copy pasted it in my professor's powerpoint that's supposed to run withour errors.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT student.admission_no, student.first_name, 
student.last_name, fee.course, fee.amount_paid
FROM student
FULL OUTER JOIN fee
ON student.admission_no = fee.admission_no;
```

Here's the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTER JOIN fee
> ON student.admission_no = fee.admission_no LIMIT 0, 25' at line 4

I just copy pasted it based on the syntax and code query provided, maybe he got something wrong?

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-can-i-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql